# Pass IEnumerable List data to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I need to pass Model.Component_GroupPanel_Component List to the controller.
I have following code but couldn't achieve it.

Code in view:-----

```
var test = { rows : @Html.Raw(Model.Component_GroupPanel_Component) ,
        cmp_DB_ID: @Model.Component_GroupPanel_Component[0].CHILD_CMP_DBID };

$("#btnUpdate").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("EditMy", "ComponentGroupPanel")",
            data: JSON.stringify(test),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
        });
    });
```

Code in controller:-----

```
public JsonResult EditMy(IEnumerable<cmp_grouppanel_cmp> rows, int cmp_DB_ID) {
            return Json(true);
        }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this. `@Html.Raw()` is server side code so you would just be posting back the initial model data unchanged so what is the point? And if you inspect the output of `@Html.Raw(Model.Component_GroupPanel_Component)` you will see that its not valid anyway (your not converting it to json)

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like you should be using an Ajax action link.  This is available in Razor so you can run it client side like your code is here and it will load the objects you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

If you need to run a partial postback, you could also use an Ajax form in Razor.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC

Hope that helps